# simplest way to default values in bash

Tags: bash

A really simple Python defaulting scheme, using an existing, but possibly empty variable goes like:

`myvar = myvar or "default"`

In bash, can I do simpler than:

```
myvar=$1  #yes, this is command line related question

if [ -z "$myvar" ]; then
    myvar=default 
fi
```

Something like a boolean OR operator?

`myvar=$myvar||default`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods for this, all using some form of parameter
expansion.

(1) `${var:-alt}` substitutes `alt` when `$var` does not exist or is empty.

```
myvar=${1:-default}
```

(2) `${var:=alt}` sets var to `alt` if `var` is not set.

```
myvar=$1
: ${myvar:=default}
echo $myvar
```

Comment: Yup, I see the duplicate now (shakes head at self) Do you want to accept your answer or delete the whole question?  Might be nicer to delete.

Comment: No preference, really. It may be better to drop the question.

Comment: oh, well, can't delete.  mucho thanks in any case.